# Copy one table to new in mysql with auto incremental values

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to copy my table into new table. I can also able to do it

If my table is like below i explain it is copied as it is with this two commands

CREATE TABLE feeds_new LIKE feeds; 
INSERT INTO feeds_new SELECT * FROM feeds;

```
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
|  1 | dog     |
|  2 | cat     |
|  4 | penguin |
|  9 | lax     |
|  23| whale   |
|  24| ostrich |
+----+---------+
```

But i want it this way.
I want all the messing auto increment to fixed in table feeds_new.

```
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
|  1 | dog     |
|  2 | cat     |
|  3 | penguin |
|  4 | lax     |
|  5 | whale   |
|  6 | ostrich |
+----+---------+
```

I dont want to copy in same way.

~thank you~

Comment: `INSERT INTO feeds_new (name) SELECT name FROM feeds` ?

Comment: this dont seems to work. because i have many row. I try puttin all of them. but not really worked

Comment: You want to explain `"but not really worked"` means? What errors did you get?

Comment: #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Is your `id` column in `feed_new` actually `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Comment: CREATE TABLE feeds_new LIKE feeds;  yes as i am copying it from old your INSERT INTO feeds_new (name) SELECT name FROM feeds ? this worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like:

```
Create table feeds_new (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      PRIMARY KEY (id),
  name varchar(100)
) ENGINE=MyISAM 
  SELECT name FROM feeds;
```

See it here on feedle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70d80/1

Answer (score 1):

if I am not wrong your main concern is to fix/reset the `auto_increment` column `id` in `feeds_new` table and insert data from `feeds` table.
In that case you can just reset the `auto_increment` column `id` like

```
ALTER TABLE feeds_new AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

then insert into it like

```
INSERT INTO feeds_new (name) SELECT name FROM feeds
```

Sidenote: This is what I understood from your post. Comment on it, if this indeed not the case. I must delete/modify the answer then.